# How to track dark mode with Komito Analytics?

Tags: komito-analytics

Does Komito Analytics support tracking of users' preferred color scheme (especially dark mode)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Preferred color scheme tracking is enabled by default in Komito Analytics' initial configuration. To disable it, set the configuration property trackColorScheme to `0`.

Check for more information at https://komito.net/posts/track-color-scheme/